# State not correctly updating on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
useEffect(() => {
    getDocuments('CL', 'birthDate, telephone', null)
    .then((res) => {
      let birthDateMD = res[0].birthDate
      let birthDate:any = new Date(birthDateMD)
      let dateMDY = `${birthDate.getDate()}/${birthDate.getMonth() + 1}/${birthDate.getFullYear()}`;
      setBirthday(dateMDY)
      setNumber(res[0].telephone)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (validBirthday && telephoneValid && name !== '' && name !== ' ' && lastName !== '' && lastName !== ' ') {
      setShow(true)
    } else {
      setShow(false)
      console.log("sad")
    }
  }, [validBirthday, name, lastName, telephoneValid])
```

Then I have all the onChange functions updating the state based on e.target.value.
I'll add just one example but all of them are using the same idea

```
const handleLastNameChange = (e: any) => {
  setLastName(e.target.value);
}
```

Also, I have a div that conditionally renders based on show value.

```
<div className={`${handles.saveButtonOne}`} onClick={submitData} style={{display: show === true ? "block" : "none"}}>
```

Lastly, here is the code for the name input.

```
      <input
        className={`${handles.inputOne}`}
        type="text"
        defaultValue={session?.namespaces?.profile?.firstName?.value}
        onChange={handleNameChange}
      />
```

On the first render, even though all the inputs are correctly filled (show would have to be true in this case), show is set to false and I need to check these values on the first render.

For eg. if I delete a word in the name, the show is set to true and the button will appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you could dispense with the show state all together, and its useEffect, by making style attribute dependent on the variables currently being checked in the if.  `style={{display: validBirthday && telephoneValid && name !== '' && name !== ' ' && lastName !== '' && lastName !== ' ' ? "block" : "none"}}`

Comment: Can you please show the render code for the name input field?

Comment: @rodix added name input in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `name` is declared using `useState`.

Try this input field using `value` instead of `defaultValue`.

```
  <input
    className={`${handles.inputOne}`}
    type="text"
    value={name}
    onChange={handleNameChange}
  />
```

And if you need to init it to some default value use the useState first argument.

recommended read [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) vs [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) components. Hope this helps.